# Maps SDK Crashes iPhone (suspected memory leak?)

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks, crash, maps

I am trying to test out the basic functionality of Google Maps SDK in xcode. I ran the code below in the Xcode simulator, and it ran just fine. However, when I try to run it on my iPhone 8, it shows my location correctly, but the map view keeps reloading itself, and eventually, my phone's memory fills up and the app crashes. I am new to using the Google Maps SDK, although I suspect it is a memory leak of some sort. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        
    
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        manager.delegate = self
        
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        print("View has loaded")
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
     
        
        print("License: \n\n\(GMSServices.openSourceLicenseInfo())")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        guard let location = locations.first else {
            return
        }
        
        let coordinate = location.coordinate
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 12.5)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.frame, camera: camera)
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        
        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = coordinate
        marker.title = "My Location"
        marker.snippet = "On Earth"
        marker.map = mapView
        
    }

}
```

..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding another map view for every location update. That will consume resources very quickly.

Instead, one should add the map view only once, before location updates are started, and inside the location update routine, only update the marker.